# FlipView Alignment problem

Tags: functions, bugs, front-end, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in V8.0 or earlier and persisting through V11.2**

---

Here's the problem with MWE:

```
FlipView[
  Framed /@ {100, 1}, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize->All
]
```

[image]

I find the following behaviour unexpected, undesired, possible bug:

- while `mouse key is pressed` now visible **next** object **left** edge is aligned to **current** object **left** edge (*invisible alread*). But it should not be dependent and be aligned as the options are stated.
- after releasing the mouse key it is aligned correctly according to options.

This makes horrible jumping each time.

Reproduced on:

WinXP V9.01

OS X  V9.00

Win7  V9.01

Comment: + `8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`

Comment: +1. Reproduced in v.8.0.4 under Win7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix is to add additional `Pane` with, unfortunately, predefined size:

```
FlipView[
  Pane[Framed[#], 50, Alignment -> Center] & /@ {100, 1}
, Alignment -> Center
, ImageSize -> All
]
```

[image]